# Strapi - Link multiple Collections

Tags: strapi

Im learning strapi and trying to create a restaurant booking concept.

1. Created the Restaurant Collection (Name, Address, Image)
2. Created the Food Category Collection (Name, Address, Image, Relation- Restaurant)
3. Created the Food Items Collection (Name, Image)

Now my doubt is..
Example: if **Restaurant A** has a category "Fried Rice" and for that, I create a Food Item "Chicken Fried rice " with one image.
I want to Create a another Food item with same name "(Chicken Fried Rice)" with different Image for Restaurant B.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Chicken Fried Rice could be different prices/images at different restaurants so they need to be unique but you want to be able to query based on either FoodCategory or by Restaurant.

This would be my suggestion:

```
Restaurant (Name, Address, Image) Relation = (hasMany -> FoodItem)
FoodCategory (Name, Address, Image) Relation = (hasMany -> FoodItem)
FoodItem (Name, Image) Relations = (belongsTo -> FoodCategory, belongsTo -> Restaurant)
```